# Fitch Style Proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

¬(A↔B) conclusion ¬A↔B
I'm having trouble with the second part of this proof.
I think I managed the first part:

1 |¬(A↔B)$\,$ $\,$ A prem.
2 ||B    $\,$   $\,$    A →intro
3 |||A    $\,$  $\,$    A →intro
4 |||B
5 ||A→B   $\,$   $\,$   →intro 3,4
6 |||A    $\,$   $\,$   A RAA intro
7 ||||B   $\,$   $\,$   A →intro
8 ||||A
9 |||B→A   $\,$   $\,$  →intro 7,8
10|||A↔B   $\,$  $\,$   ↔ intro 5,9
11||¬A    $\,$   $\,$   RAA(6) 1,10
12|B→¬A   $\,$  $\,$    →intro 2,11

I was going to do the same for ¬A→B, but I don't see how I
can conclude B when I start with ¬A.
If anyone could help me.

Comment: Good work so far, and follow Bram's advice to complete.

Comment: I do not think that step 6 is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use the basic method of doing this by a RAA: assume $\neg B$, try and get to $A \leftrightarrow B$ to get your contradiction, and use RAA to conclude $\neg \neg B$, and from that you can get $B$

Also, to get to $A \leftrightarrow B$ once you have assumed $\neg A $ and $\neg B$: same idea. Just going left to right: assume $A$. Now assume $\neg B$. Get a contradiction between $A$ and $\neg A$. So by RAA $\neg \neg B$ and thus $B$

Comment: Do you mean, first assume ¬A and then ¬B and then get A↔B by first assuming A (which will contradict ¬A) and then B (which will contradict ¬B )?

Comment: **Explosion!** (*Ex falso quodlibet*)  $$\tiny\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{\neg A}{\fitch{\neg B}{\fitch{A}{\bot \\ B}\\~~\vdots}\\~~\vdots}$$

Comment: Thank you both, I think I managed to solve it with your help.